# Mocking a repository with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, repository, moq

To mock a repository, I use the code below. I don't understand why the variable `empl` is always `null`.

Do you know what I missed ?

Thanks,

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var employee = new Employee { EmployeeID = 1, Code = "Code", FirstName = "MyFirstName", LastName = "MyName" };

    var employeeRepository = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
    employeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Add(employee)).Verifiable();

    var employeeService = new EmployeeService(employeeRepository.Object);
    var empl = employeeService.GetById(1);

    Assert.IsNotNull(empl);
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IEmployeeRepository : IBaseRepository<Employee> {}

public interface IBaseRepository<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Get();
    TEntity Add(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    int Count();
}

public class EmployeeService
{
    private IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;

    public EmployeeService(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
    {
        _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
    }

    public Employee GetById(int id)
    {
        return _employeeRepository.Get().FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == id);
    }

    public void Add(Employee employee)
    {
        _employeeRepository.Add(employee);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mocking wrong method. Mock `Get`:

```
employeeRepository.Setup(x => x.Get()).Returns(new[] { employee });
```

Mock is a *fake object*, it doesn't have any logic in methods. You have to *tell it* how exactly it should behave (setup) so that in your test this behavior can be replayed.