# How to eliminate the dependency on the database from a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

Is it possible to create a unit test for this method?

```
public void CheckIndicatorMeasurementRecordingValidity(IndicatorMeasurementRecording indicatorMeasurementRecording)
{
   var isDateRangeOverLapping = this.db.IndicatorMeasurementRecordingRepository.Any(r => r.IndicatorId == indicatorMeasurementRecording.Indicator.Id && r.Id != indicatorMeasurementRecording.Id
                && r.RecordingDateRange.ToDateTime >= indicatorMeasurementRecording.RecordingDateRange.FromDateTime
                && r.RecordingDateRange.FromDateTime <= indicatorMeasurementRecording.RecordingDateRange.ToDateTime);

   if (isDateRangeOverLapping)
   {
       throw new GrcUserException(IndicatorThresholdValidityManagementLocal.DateRangeOverlapping);
   }
}
```

I tried to create the test like this

```
[TestMethod]
public void Indicator_measurement_date_range_overlapping_shall_throw_exception()
{
    var indicator = new Indicator();
    var oldIndicatorMeasurementRecording = new IndicatorMeasurementRecording();
    var newIndicatorMeasurementRecording = new IndicatorMeasurementRecording();
    var errorMessage = string.Empty;

    oldIndicatorMeasurementRecording.Id = 1;
    oldIndicatorMeasurementRecording.RecordingDateRange.FromDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);
    oldIndicatorMeasurementRecording.RecordingDateRange.ToDateTime = DateTime.Today;
    indicator.IndicatorMeasurementRecordings.Add(oldIndicatorMeasurementRecording);

    oldIndicatorMeasurementRecording.Id = 2;
    newIndicatorMeasurementRecording.RecordingDateRange.FromDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);
    newIndicatorMeasurementRecording.RecordingDateRange.ToDateTime = DateTime.Today;
    newIndicatorMeasurementRecording.Indicator = indicator;

    try
    {
        this.indicatorValidityProxy.CheckIndicatorMeasurementRecordingValidity(newIndicatorMeasurementRecording);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMessage = ex.Message;
    }

    Assert.AreEqual(IndicatorThresholdValidityManagementLocal.DateRangeOverlapping, errorMessage);
}
```

The problem is, the test always fails because 
this.db.IndicatorMeasurementRecordingRepository.Count for test is always 0.
For development purpose it always returns the correct number. Only in the test purpose is it 0.

Can anyone tell me why `this.db.IndicatorMeasurementRecordingRepository.Count` for test purpose is always 0? And what is the best practice for writing the test for my case?

Comment: I think you _should_ put that `this.db` thing behind an abstraction (read interface), and then you could mock the calls to it, verify the calls etc. Also there are tons of such [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690868/mocking-a-repository-with-moq) on SO.

Comment: Yes, this.db is IDBContext so you can create mock of this interface and do setup for all the calls and return mock response to test the behaviour

Comment: Can anyone help me to give example unit test using moq for my case? Many many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the.db is, but assuming `public class MyContext : DbContext` and `this.db` is of type `MyContext` then with Mock you can:

```
var contextMock = new Mock<MyContext>();
// arrange more
```

Essentially you would configure the contextMock to return a known set of your objects (`IndicatorMeasurementRecording`?) when the `IndicatorMeasurementRecordingRepository` is queried. Something like:

```
var dbSetMock = new Mock<IDbSet<DbEntity>>();
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
dbSetMock.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

var contextMock = new Mock<MyContext>();
contextMock 
    .Setup(x => x.DbEntities)
    .Returns(dbSetMock.Object);
```

Where data would be a list of your objects to be returned from the mock.

Some links / examples to help you:

- The [Moq quickstart is here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).
- [Testing with a Mocking Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx) (MSDN)
- [How to mock dbcontext and dbset with MOQ for Unit Testing](http://aikmeng.com/post/62817541825/how-to-mock-dbcontext-and-dbset-with-moq-for-unit) (above air code cribbed from here)
- [How ef6 enables mocking dbsets more easily](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/how-ef6-enables-mocking-dbsets-more-easily/)

I can't recreate your test case as there is too much code not there, but if you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I am more than happy to look at the test in more detail.